# How to balance an unbalanced panel data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, panel-data, plm

Suppose I have the following unbalance pandel data:

```
unbalanced.panel = structure(list(firm = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"B", "C", "C"), ind = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), year = c(2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2012, 2013), 
    charac1 = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z", "g", 
    "h", "h"), var1 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 15, 29, 31, 13, 
    2)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
   firm    ind  year charac1  var1
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A         1  2010 x          11
 2 A         1  2011 x          12
 3 A         1  2012 x          13
 4 A         1  2013 x          14
 5 B         2  2011 y          15
 6 B         2  2013 y          18
 7 A         2  2011 z          15
 8 A         2  2012 z          29
 9 B         1  2010 g          31
10 C         1  2012 h          13
11 C         1  2013 h           2
```

Where each unique group (individual) is identified by the combination of `firm` and `ind`, i.e. individual "A1" is different from "A2" individual. And the time index is given by `year` variable.

What I want is to balance the panal data (index = (individual = firm-ind, time = year)) filling the implicit missing gaps with NA's.

The desired result is as follows:

```
   firm    ind  year charac1  var1
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 A         1  2010 x          11
 2 A         1  2011 x          12
 3 A         1  2012 x          13
 4 A         1  2013 x          14
 5 B         2  2010 y          NA
 6 B         2  2011 y          15
 7 B         2  2012 y          NA
 8 B         2  2013 y          18
 9 A         2  2010 z          NA
10 A         2  2011 z          15
11 A         2  2012 z          29
12 A         2  2013 z          NA
13 B         1  2010 g          31
14 B         1  2011 g          NA
15 B         1  2012 g          NA
16 B         1  2013 g          NA
17 C         1  2010 h          NA
18 C         1  2011 h          NA
19 C         1  2012 h          13
20 C         1  2013 h           2
```

I tried to use `plm::make.pbalanced(unbalanced.panel, balance.type = "fill")` but I got the following error:

> Error in mode<-(tmp, value = id_orig_typeof) : invalid to change the storage mode of a factor

I even tried to used `tidyr::complete()`, but it doesn't help to achieve my desired balanced panel.

These are my request: When an unique individual (firm-ind) is missing a year row, time-variant variables (var1) must be filled with NA, but time-invariant variables such as characteristics (charact1) should be filled with the unique value.

What's the problem with `tidyr::complete()` approach? It doesn't allow me to differentiate between time-invariant and time-variant variables to be filled or expanded. And it doesn't identify uniquely individual-index (in this case firm-ind).

```
unbalanced.panel >%>
  tidyr::complete(firm, year, nesting(var1))
```

Above code makes appear a new individual "C2" and fills with NA the time-invariant variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `complete` from the `tidyr` package. The key is to set `nesting` properly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

balanced.panel <- unbalanced.panel %>%  
  complete(nesting(firm, ind, charac1), year = full_seq(year, period = 1))
balanced.panel
# # A tibble: 20 x 5
#  firm    ind charac1  year  var1
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 A         1 x        2010    11
#  2 A         1 x        2011    12
#  3 A         1 x        2012    13
#  4 A         1 x        2013    14
#  5 A         2 z        2010    NA
#  6 A         2 z        2011    15
#  7 A         2 z        2012    29
#  8 A         2 z        2013    NA
#  9 B         1 g        2010    31
# 10 B         1 g        2011    NA
# 11 B         1 g        2012    NA
# 12 B         1 g        2013    NA
# 13 B         2 y        2010    NA
# 14 B         2 y        2011    15
# 15 B         2 y        2012    NA
# 16 B         2 y        2013    18
# 17 C         1 h        2010    NA
# 18 C         1 h        2011    NA
# 19 C         1 h        2012    13
# 20 C         1 h        2013     2
```

Comment: How can I use ```full_seq(year, period = 1)``` when year is a ```Date``` class?
I mean, in my case year is a yearly Date variable with "%Y-%m-%d" format, using ```full_seq(year, period = 1)``` doesn't fill the complete date window. Besides, I'd like to generalize this approach with other frequency Date variable, such as daily, monthly or quaterly data. Thanks

Comment: You did not show your year column as a date class in your example, so it is difficult to answer. You can always use seq.Date to generate the date sequence you want. It does not need to use full_seq.

Comment: Had the same problem as @Cristhian, but my year variable was an "numeric".

Answer (score 2):

`plm` uses two dimensions for panel data (individual, time). First, make a variable that reflects the individual dimension by combining the two variables you have to refer to an individual, let us call this variable `idvar`. For conciseness, let us call the data set `u`. For `plm`'s data manipulating functions, it is easier to work on a `pdata.frame`.
Combining all those hints in code, use something like the following:

```
u <- unbalanced.panel
u$idvar <- paste(u$firm, u$ind)
pu <- pdata.frame(u, index = c("idvar", "year"))
make.pbalanced(pu, balance.type = "fill")

#         firm ind year charac1 var1 idvar
# A 1-2010    A   1 2010       x   11   A 1
# A 1-2011    A   1 2011       x   12   A 1
# A 1-2012    A   1 2012       x   13   A 1
# A 1-2013    A   1 2013       x   14   A 1
# A 2-2010 <NA>  NA 2010    <NA>   NA   A 2
# A 2-2011    A   2 2011       z   15   A 2
# A 2-2012    A   2 2012       z   29   A 2
# A 2-2013 <NA>  NA 2013    <NA>   NA   A 2
# B 1-2010    B   1 2010       g   31   B 1
# B 1-2011 <NA>  NA 2011    <NA>   NA   B 1
# B 1-2012 <NA>  NA 2012    <NA>   NA   B 1
# B 1-2013 <NA>  NA 2013    <NA>   NA   B 1
# B 2-2010 <NA>  NA 2010    <NA>   NA   B 2
# B 2-2011    B   2 2011       y   15   B 2
# B 2-2012 <NA>  NA 2012    <NA>   NA   B 2
# B 2-2013    B   2 2013       y   18   B 2
# C 1-2010 <NA>  NA 2010    <NA>   NA   C 1
# C 1-2011 <NA>  NA 2011    <NA>   NA   C 1
# C 1-2012    C   1 2012       h   13   C 1
# C 1-2013    C   1 2013       h    2   C 1
```

Comment: Then, how would you fill the NA gererated in charac1, firm, ind? I am trying `fill()` but get's me back to the unbalanced panel.

Comment: You can use the usual data frame insert methods (in conjunction with subsetting) of base R. They work also for a pdata.frame. `fill()` is not from base R, not from plm. Likely you mean `tidyr::fill()` - I do not think it is aware of the special pdata.frame structure and it might destroy what you achieved; check its documentation (I haven't). You can convert the pdata.frame in a data frame by `plm::as.data.frame` and then work with anything that works on a data frame.